# Are there any alternatives to Gigaspaces?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, gigaspaces

Anything thats as good and as stable and as feature-rich as gigaspaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gigaspaces is top notch as far as a Javaspaces implementation goes for scalability and performance. Are you restricted to a Javaspaces implementation? Blitz Javaspaces is top notch for a free product.

Answer (score 10):

As the first answer says, what are your criteria?  There's a number of commercial and open-source tools in the same space (but not Javaspaces-based):

- [Oracle Coherence](http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH34UG/Coherence+3.4+Home)
- [Gemstone's Gemfire](http://www.gemstone.com/products/gemfire/)
- [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org) (a degree of overlap, but not quite in the same space)
- [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com) (does the grid bit, but not the distributed cache bit)

Answer (score 4):

[Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/)
Some comparisons:
[Comparison1](http://java.dzone.com/articles/comparison-gridcloud-computing)
[Comparison2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/comparison-gridcloud-computing-0)

Cheers!
P.S.: I am also interested in people opinions regarding this matter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking a look at Gartner's "Competitive Landscape: In-Memory Data Grids" at http://www.gartner.com/technology/reprints.do?id=1-1HCCIMJ&ct=130718&st=sb

Comment: Access to this content has now expired.

Comment: Yeah, I think those "reprint" things are used for marketing ... only valid for a certain period of time.